# URL externa gestor de menú Joomla

Tags: php, joomla3, cms

Un equipo de desarrollo me pidió agregar una url especial para que desde ella se ejecute un APK Android, la url sería algo como esto:

```
<a href="streamplay://apkplay">Abrir App</a>
```

El tema es que Joomla me da el siguiente error tratando de grabar esa url:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de un módulo normal (haciendo referencia a un artículo simple) funciona sin inconveniente y levanta la app, pero desde el gestor de menú no ha sido posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente no es posible de la forma que lo pretendes hacer, pues Joomla verifica que el protocolo esté entre los permitidos, a continuación el código que hace dicha verificación:

```
        if (strstr($data['link'], ':'))
        {
            $segments = explode(':', $data['link']);
            $protocol = strtolower($segments[0]);
            $scheme   = array(
                'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'gopher', 'mailto',
                'news', 'prospero', 'telnet', 'rlogin', 'tn3270', 'wais',
                'mid', 'cid', 'nntp', 'tel', 'urn', 'ldap', 'file', 'fax',
                'modem', 'git', 'sms',
            );

            if (!in_array($protocol, $scheme))
            {
                $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_SAVE_NOT_PERMITTED'), 'warning');
                $this->setRedirect(
                    JRoute::_('index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_item . $this->getRedirectToItemAppend($recordId), false)
                );

                return false;
            }
        }
```

La solución "sencilla", sin tener que usar extensiones, sería utilizando JavaScript, agregando como enlace `#` y una clase "única" (en este caso utilicé `clase`) y capturando el click, algo así:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){   
  $('.clase').click(function () {
    window.location.href = 'streamplay://apkplay'
  });
});
```

Comment: Excelente... Bueno hice en test local modificando la validacion y añadi lo que necesito, de momento funcionó, será recomendable hacer eso? Digo es un arreglo de strings, no creo que cause mucho dañlo o si?

Comment: No es una buena práctica, y el mayor problema es al momento de actualizar, si la nueva versión de Joomla sobreescribe tus cambios, tendrás que hacerlos de nuevo.

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias... Y si para tener en cuenta, no creo que se actualice, mas bien se está tratando de migrar a otra plataforma.